# Repeating values in rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My table having below records.

```
SNO NAME TELNO
1   A    12345
2   A     
3   A   
4   B    78901
5   B
```

i need select statement with telno 12345 should display for the employee whose Name is 'A' for the rows SNO(1,2,3)

and telno no 78901 should display for the employee whose name is 'B' for the rows SNO(4,5).

Sample Output

```
SNO NAME TELNO
1   A    12345
2   A    12345 
3   A    12345
4   B    78901
5   B    78901
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is a self join assuming the name's are unique. You really didn't give a complex enough sample set. Another way is a derived table.

```
declare @table table (SNO int, [NAME] char(1), TELNO int)
insert into @table
values
(1,'A',12345),
(2,'A',null),
(3,'A',null),   
(4,'B',78901),
(5,'B',null)  


select
    a.SNO
    ,a.NAME
    ,b.TELNO
from @table a
inner join @table b on b.NAME = a.NAME
where b.TELNO is not null


select
    a.SNO
    ,a.NAME
    ,b.TELNO
from @table a
left join (select name, max(TELNO) telno from @table group by name) b on b.NAME = a.NAME
```

Comment: No problem @Ram